# Use jquery validation plugin to validate complex array of input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using  jquery validation plugin to validate complex array of inputs.

HTML form

```
<form class="test_frm" action="" method="post" >
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[0][type]" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[0][rate]" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[0][percent]" />

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[1][type]" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[1][rate]" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[1][percent]" />

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[2][type]" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[2][rate]" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[2][percent]" />
</form>
```

JS code

```
$(function () {
    $(".test_frm").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        },
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            'rateType[]': {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What I need with validation is it **should be true if at least one text input is filled**. But this code not working even though it worked for simple array inputs. Would be a great help if someone know how to do this. And great if **it's not depend on array value like [0] or [type]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rules: {
    'rateType[]': {  // <- does not match any NAME on the form!
        required: true
    }
}
```

The identifier used within your options **must** match the name of a field.

```
rules: {
    'rateType[0][type]': {
        required: true
    },
    'rateType[0][rate]': {
        required: true
    },
    'rateType[0][percent]': {
        required: true
    },
    // etc. etc. for every field on the form.
}
```

Since this is quite cumbersome, you can use [the `.rules()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) along with a more generic selector like a **"starts with"**.  You'll need an `.each()` since this validation plugin does not accept a selection with more than one element.

```
$("[name^='rateType']").each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});
```

**NOTE**: The `.rules()` method can only be called after you've called your `.validate()` method.

```
$(function () {

    $(".test_frm").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        },
        ignore: [],
    });

    $("[name^='rateType']").each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true
        });
    });

});
```

---

Alternatively, if you want a HTML solution, you can just add an inline class or an HTML5 attribute and the jQuery Validate plugin will pick up either one automatically.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[0][type]" class="required" />
```

OR

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="rateType[0][type]" required="required" />
```